# Single Page Application JWT, token refreshing vs long lived tokens

Tags: rest, security, authentication, jwt, single-page-application

I'm beginning a Single Page Application, and I'm using JSON Web Tokens to Authenticate client side (JS Client with Server API).

In my app, user provides credentials (app auth, facebook, google) and then server checks for user existence and returns a token.

Client JS adds token to each request in order to use the Server API.

When token gets issued, it has an expiry time and a max refresh time.  If a set a short expiration time for the token and a "good" max refresh time I get into having to know when to refresh tokens.  Best approach I've found so far, is to check on client when the token is being expired (5 minutes before) and then issue a refresh request.  Then I'd get a new token.  This could be done till max refresh time is reached.  Then, user should have to reauthenticate.

Another approach I've seen, is that on server, if token is nearly or has just expired, it gets auto-refreshed and returned to client (which has to detect token change and store it)

But... what is the difference between this and having a single token that is long lived?

Is having a short lived access token which can be renewed with a refresh token tons of times better than having a single long lived access token?

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason to use a short-lived token is to defend against [session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), when an adversary, through one method or another, steals session credentials (in this case, the token) and acts maliciously in the victim's session. The shorter-lived the token, the less time the attacker has to carry out whatever malicious activity they have planned.

Comment: I realise that, but if token gets auto refreshed, stealing 1 token means having it autorefreshed till max refresh time, so is more or less the same as having a long one, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by auto-refreshed, exactly? The standard model is to send a refresh token with the original access token, which can be redeemed for a single new token. It should not be be sent with every request. If a user attempts to connect with an expired access token, the server will request the refresh token (or the client, knowing the token is expired, will make a refresh request). If the client does not have it, they will be prompted to login. Once they log in, all extant refresh and access tokens will be invalidated, to be replaced by the new pair sent by the server.

Comment: The key is that using a refresh token should invalidate all extant access tokens, *and* that refresh token. So if a refresh token is stolen, and an attacker uses it to get a new refresh token and access token, the user will be prompted to login on their next request, as their tokens are now invalid. That login will, as said above, create a new token pair and invalidate the token pair the attacker has gained.

Comment: I'll try to explain.  I'm using tymondesigns/jwt-auth package for Laravel.  Here, when you validate user credentials, server issues one token.  This token is valid till expiration time, but ALSO it's refreshable till max_refresh_time.  Refresh token doesn't get issued.

Refresh can be forced, passing a valid token, and real effect is that I get a new token and invalidate previous one.

Comment: With that method, the reason for the longer refresh time is likely to allow users to share state across multiple, non-consecutive sessions, i.e. they can log in on Tuesday and resume in the same place Wednesday without having to log in again. This would also force an attacker to fetch a new token if they attempt to use a token after expires, which a user would invalidate next time they try to connect and have to log in. From a pure security perspective, its definitely not ideal, but the UX appeal is pretty apparent. This also removes the "overhead" of having to manage two tokens